# nltk-hook unable to find nltk_data

Tags: python, nltk, hook, pyinstaller

When using pyinstaller to build an executable I get

> unable to find /home/usr/nltk_data

when adding binary and data files.

I've tried almost every single solution on the internet

Answer (score 13):

Change hook-nltk.py file to this

```
import os
import nltk
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_data_files
# add datas for nltk
datas = collect_data_files('nltk', False)

# loop through the data directories and add them
for p in nltk.data.path:
    if os.path.exists(p):
        datas.append((p, "nltk_data"))

# nltk.chunk.named_entity should be included
hiddenimports = ["nltk.chunk.named_entity"]
```

and
change remove the double space to single space of file "pyi_rth_nltk.py" instead of  "pyi_rth__nltk.py".This file can be at \Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks

Comment: anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks

Comment: C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks Location for windows

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problems editing the pyinstaller nltk-hook (inside python3). After much research, I decided to go it alone in the code structure. I solved my problem by commenting on the lines:
`datas=[]`

`'''for p in nltk.data.path:
    datas.append((p, "nltk_data"))'''`

`hiddenimports = ["nltk.chunk.named_entity"]`

What's more, you need to rename the file: pyi_rth__nltk.cpython-36.pyc to pyi_rth_nltk.cpython-36.pyc  This file have 1 more underline. Warning with the python version.